# GCP Authentication Envoy Filter with Anthos Service Mesh

Tags: google-cloud-platform, istio, envoyproxy

I am trying to get the [GCP Auth Filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.22.2/configuration/http/http_filters/gcp_authn_filter#config-http-filters-gcp-authn) running.

According to [Envoy's release notes](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/version_history/v1.22/v1.22.0.html), it should be available with 1.22.

I am using [Anthos Service Mesh 1.14](https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/release-notes), [which should be based to Envoy 1.22](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/proxy-cmd/#what-envoy-version-is-istio-using)

Output is:

```
kubectl exec -it mypod -c istio-proxy   -- pilot-agent request GET server_info --log_as_json | jq {version}
{
  "version": "70cf007ae0dcec3e226544e16af578d3b980f29f/1.22.2/Modified/RELEASE/BoringSSL-FIPS"
}
```

Envoy Filter (more or less like the [Rate Limiting example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/#global-rate-limit) )

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: filter-gcp
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    # select by label in the same namespace
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    # The Envoy config you want to modify
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
              subFilter:
                name: "envoy.filters.http.router"
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.filters.http.gcp_authn
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.gcp_authn.v3.GcpAuthnFilterConfig
            http_uri:
              uri: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=[AUDIENCE]
              cluster: metadata
              timeout: 10ms
```

Getting the following errors in the Ingress Gateway log:

```
[libprotobuf WARNING external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:2139] Can't print proto content: proto type type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.gcp_authn.v3.GcpAuthnFilterConfig not found
[libprotobuf WARNING external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:2139] Can't print proto content: proto type type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.gcp_authn.v3.GcpAuthnFilterConfig not found
2022-08-09T08:05:21.513377Z warning envoy config    gRPC config for type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.listener.v3.Listener rejected: Error adding/updating listener(s) 0.0.0.0_80: Didn't find a registered implementation for name: 'envoy.filters.http.gcp_authn'
```

So is this filter supported, or am I doing something wrong? Or is the ASM Envoy version maybe modified so that is does not include that filter?

Comment: Envoy filters are not supported in ASM https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/supported-features#crd_support

Comment: @boredabdel they are not supported, but it is still possible to create Envoy Filters in general, the doc is somewhat ambiguous: That sign indicates either the feature isn't available or it isn't supported in Anthos Service Mesh 1.14.1.

Comment: Can you try adding a - to  name: envoy.filters.http.gcp_authn ?

Comment: do you mean, make it an YAML array? with `- name: envoy.filters.http.gcp_authn` that cannot be applied with kubectl

Comment: Ignore that. Can you try to add the type to the filters please

      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager

and

          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router

Comment: you mean to the filterChain config? Then it fails the validation since these are not part of the EnvoyFilter CRD:
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/#EnvoyFilter-ListenerMatch-FilterMatch
error message:
unknown field "typed_config" in io.istio.networking.v1alpha3.EnvoyFilter.spec.configPatches.match.listener.filterChain.filter

Comment: I think the issue is that the filterChain is not selection the proper proto version. envoy.filters.http.gcp_authn is supported as part of the extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpFilter.

Maybe try specifying the @type for the subFilter ?

Comment: Well in the context of the Istio EnvoyFilter it is not possible to add any other stuff, since then the validation of the CRD fails...

Comment: Not related to your issue: But I am trying to figure out a way to convert EnvoyFilters into some kind of a config supported by managed anthos service mesh. Posting it here in case anybody knows a way. Thanks!

Comment: @PramodSetlur envoyfilters _should_ work with managed asm as well. just because it is not supported it does not work they don't work. But you could try WasmPlugins as well... (btw you could ask an own question as well)

Comment: @user140547 Thank you, will check out WasmPlugins. We are currently talking to our GCP reps to figure out a way; more specifically, the response header indicating the backend server (https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13861) needs to be removed. EnvoyFilters could do it, but we are paranoid to use, incase the managed control plane gets updated to a version that does not support EnvoyFilters. Will post it here if i find anything.